Return 0 only if query result is Nan(null) else return Nan
This got me confused for a few hours, i already found my answer but wanted to ask if this correct.
I have a metric that is always 1 in value, or null.
the metric has 2 labels, id and name.
So in grafana wanted to graph in a stat panel the label values when the metric is 1.
metric{id="$id"}
Legend: {{id}} - {{name}}

If the metric is null, i wanted to show "Not connected", there is no way in grafana to use label values outside of the Legend for the query as far as i know, and the Value of the metric has to be hidden, so we are stuck with legends.
I made another query to do the inverse, basically, return null if query is 1, and return 0 if query is null.
After spending some time i come up with this, works but
(metric{id="$id"} default 0) == 0
Legend: "Not Connected"

My question is why can't we check for nulls, like (nil if (metric{id="$id"} == 1)) default 0, or (0 if (metric{id="$id"} == nil) default nil
seems more descriptive to me, don't know id there is another way to do it out of curiosity.

Why not something like vector(0) unless on() metric{id="$id"} if you don't care about resulting vector labels?

Alternatively, since you are not using multi-select option for variable id (at least AFAICT), panel's "No value" option should do the trick for you without employing clever queries.

The problem with "No Value" option is that only works if you show the Value, and the value has to be hidden, it has no meaning and clutters the visualization, it's a shortcomming on grafana side.

vector(0) unless on() metric{id="$id"} Works, thanks. Seems more descriptive.

(metric{id="$id"} default 0) == 0
Legend: "Not Connected"

Returns 0 only if query is null. else returns null if the metric returns 1.
